# Python - How to write a program to get the remainder of the quotient of two numbers without using %, //, / or any multiplication?

Tags: python, modulo

I'm really stuck on this. I could do it with integer division and multiplication but I have no idea how to find the remainder without any of these operators. (can't import anything either. the main premise is to use while loops).

Comment: How do school kids learn division? Subtract over and over again.

Comment: `divmod(666, 42)[1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> def solution(a, b):
...     while a >= b:
...         a -= b
...     return a
... 
>>> solution(11, 5) == (11 % 5)
True
>>> solution(763, 47) == (763 % 47)
True
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I overthought that way too much

Comment: @Devin You should accept this answer if it solved your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Just an efficient one:

```
def mod(a, b):
    if a >= b:
        a = mod(a, b + b)
    if a < b:
        return a
    return a - b
```

Demo:

```
>>> a, b = 75349157395712349036170927572349157024, 543791534729045
>>> mod(a, b)
510757213184524
>>> a % b
510757213184524
```